# Can I save stuck bitcoins by creating a completely new transaction?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend, replace-by-fee

I tried to make a bitcoin payment but accidently set a too low transaction fee so it got stuck. By now the payment is cancelled so I don't want to do this transaction anymore.

Can I now instruct my bitcoin adress to send the bitcoins somewhere else (instead of the stuck transaction) by broadcasting a completely new transaction? I used Bitcoin Core for the initial transaction.

P.S. Nobodys waiting anymore for the initial paymant so I'm not trying to scam anyone here.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Please see this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) and possibly this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22365/75001) for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it as long as the previous transaction does not get confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "unstick" a Bitcoin transaction. That transaction has already been sent to the new wallet, it's just not yet confirmed. Bitcoin transactions are inherently irreversible.

You can ask the owner of the receiving wallet to send the transaction onward to a wallet you own, and piggyback a new, additional fee on it to send it back to you. The sum of the two fees may attract a miner.

Although theoretically not allowed, you can attempt to "send the Bitcoins somewhere else," but that would effectively be a doublespend. You can try to doublespend the transaction with a higher fee back to a wallet that you own and hope some miner picks up the new, questionable transaction. The original spend would then be orphaned. See: [Could any standard fee transaction be double spent by using a higher fee?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/could-any-standard-fee-transaction-be-double-spent-by-using-a-higher-fee)